# Is it possible to undo the editing of pictures of which you don't have the originals anymore?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I did much photoshopping on pictures, of which I can't remember the original. The originals are gone. Can I retrieve them still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds are against it, if you didn't take care of your files then you really only have yourself to blame.

That said, there is a feature called "previous versions" in Windows which has been around for quite some time and, if enabled, may save your bacon provided system restore was/is configured correctly, which it may have been by default.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 7):

Probably not, unless you saved in Photoshop's native format and the files have a layer which corresponds to the original unaltered image. If you saved in jpeg or another "flat" format — or if you edited the image directly without using layers — you are going to be out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to get original images back in Photoshop. File recovery software are available. There is no way if you overwrite the edited one with the originals..